# The immediate place where an uploaded file is stored

Tags: php, web-applications

When I upload a file, where is the immediate place the file will go to on the webserver? Is there anyway to configure this place?

Comment: What web server are you using? It will depend on that.

Comment: WebDAV? PHP? ASP.NET? be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of PHP they go to [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) or system default (usually /tmp).

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php